# Update react-native state using async/await

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await

I am trying to immediately update a boolean state variable in react native.  the await keyword does not work however.  because state setter functions are asynchronous, how can I do this using async / await?  In vscode, the await in front of the setLike setter function has a message : "await has no effect on this type of expression"

```
const likeIt = async () => {
        console.log('like pressed');
        console.log('liked? before set', like);  //**false**
        await setLike(like => !like);
        console.log('liked? after set', like);  //**should be true but getting false**
        const axiosAuth = await axiosWithAuth();
        const userToken = axiosAuth.defaults.headers.Authorization;

        if (like) {
            axiosAuth.post(`https://url`,{})
                .then(res => {
                    console.log('response from post like: ', res.data);
                })
                .catch(err => console.log('error in post like', err.message))
        } else {
            axiosAuth.delete(`https://url`)
                .then(res => console.log('res from unlike', res.data))
                .catch(err => console.log('err from unlike', err))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If we talk about react hooks, you should to know that `useState()` return array of two values. The second value is a dispatch function which we use to change value of state. And this functions are synchronous.
In your example this dispatch function is `setLike()` (and it is synchronous function).  So `await` keyword do not work for them actually.

React has special system in the hood to work with changing state. This system wait for batch of changing states and then update our state and rerender component. Before that update of state and rerender of component, our `likeIt()` function will be done.

You could use `useEffect()` lifecycle method to handle change of `like` state.

For example:

```js
const likeIt = async () => {
        console.log('like pressed');
        console.log('liked? before set', like);  //**false**
        await setLike(like => !like);
}

useEffect(() => {
        console.log('liked? after set', like); //**true**
        ...
}, [like]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`await useState();` will not work.

Here is a possible solution that rather works with a temp variable in your `likeIt()` function.

```
function App() {
  const [like, setLike] = useState(false);

   const likeIt = async () => {
     let temp = !like;

     const axiosAuth = await axiosWithAuth();
     const userToken = axiosAuth.defaults.headers.Authorization;

    if (!temp) {
      axiosAuth.delete(`https://url`)
              .then(res => console.log('res from unlike', res.data))
              .catch(err => console.log('err from unlike', err))
    } else {
      axiosAuth.post(`https://url`,{})
            .then(res => {
                console.log('response from post like: ', res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log('error in post like', err.message))
    }

    setLike(temp);
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={likeIt}>{like === true ? 'Liked' : 'Not Liked'}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks so much @chev.  creating a temp variable for the state variable was what I needed to get the logic of the function working.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting compiling errors due to await setLike()?
If not, it is a small issue that would be confusing for some people on VScode.
Please kindly check https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80853

Comment: If not, then you can ignore it.